# error segmentation fault in dynamic array

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, vector

I am solving [this problem on dynamic array](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/dynamic-array/problem) in which input  first line contains two space-separated integers,n, the size of arr to create, and q, the number of queries, respectively.
Each of the q subsequent lines contains a query string,`queries[i]`. it expects to return `int[]`: the results of each type 2 query in the order they are presented.

i tried to attempt as below and my code seems fine to me but it gives segmentation fault error. please help me where I am getting conceptually wrong. thanks.

problem: Declare a 2-dimensional array,`arr` , of `n` empty arrays. All arrays are zero indexed.
Declare an integer,last answer , and initialize it to `zero`.

There are `2` types of `queries`, given as an array of strings for you to parse:

Query: 1 x y

Let `idx=((queries[i][1]^last_answer)%n);`.
Append the integer y  to `arr[idx]`.

Query: 2 x y

Let `idx=((queries[i][1]^last_answer)%n);`.
Assign `last_answer=arr[idx][queries[i][2]%(arr[idx].size())]` .
Store the new value of `last_answer` to an answers array.

input:
2 5

1 0 5

1 1 7

1 0 3

2 1 0

2 1 1

output:

7

3

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
//The function is expected to return an INTEGER_ARRAY,fuction accepts parameter 1) INTEGER n & (2) 2D_INTEGER_ARRAY queries
vector<int> dynamicArray(int n, vector<vector<int>> queries) {
    vector<vector<int>>arr;
    vector<int>answer;
    int last_answer=0;
    int q=queries.size();
    for(int i=0;i<q;i++){
        if(queries[i][0]==1){
            int idx=((queries[i][1]^last_answer)%n);
            arr[idx].push_back(queries[i][2]);
        }
        else{
            int idx=((queries[i][1]^last_answer)%n);
            last_answer=arr[idx][queries[i][2]%(arr[idx].size())];
            answer.push_back(last_answer);
        }
    }
    return answer;
}
int main(){
    int n,q;
    vector<vector<int>>querie;
    cin>>n>>q;
    for(int i=0;i<q;i++){
        cin>>querie[i][0]>>querie[i][1]>>querie[i][2];
    }
    vector<int>result=dynamicArray(n,querie);
    for(size_t i=0;i<result.size();i++){
        cout<<result[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: please provide a [mre] with inputs and expected outputs and explain how the code is supposed to work. Have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: `arr` is an empty array and accessing any index is out-of-bounds. You correctly push elements to answer and to the (non-existing) elements of `arr`, but you never add an element to `arr`

Comment: @alan sir,yes sir i tried debugging a lot and have also added links of the exact question

Comment: a [mre] needs to be within the question and not rely on external links

Comment: You should also include the information you got while using the debugger, such as the line that caused the crash and the reason for the crash.

Comment: @alan sir thanks for the kind advice for asking question in a proper way, have modified it and my debugger actually outputs no error but it does not give any output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are accessing elements of `vector` without allocating them.

[`resize()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize) is useful to allocate elements.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
//The function is expected to return an INTEGER_ARRAY,fuction accepts parameter 1) INTEGER n & (2) 2D_INTEGER_ARRAY queries
vector<int> dynamicArray(int n, vector<vector<int>> queries) {
    vector<vector<int>>arr;
    vector<int>answer;
    int last_answer=0;
    int q=queries.size();
    arr.resize(n); // *** allocate elements ***
    for(int i=0;i<q;i++){
        if(queries[i][0]==1){
            int idx=((queries[i][1]^last_answer)%n);
            arr[idx].push_back(queries[i][2]);
        }
        else{
            int idx=((queries[i][1]^last_answer)%n);
            last_answer=arr[idx][queries[i][2]%(arr[idx].size())];
            answer.push_back(last_answer);
        }
    }
    return answer;
}
int main(){
    int n,q;
    vector<vector<int>>querie;
    cin>>n>>q;
    querie.resize(q, vector<int>(3)); // *** allocate elements ***
    for(int i=0;i<q;i++){
        cin>>querie[i][0]>>querie[i][1]>>querie[i][2];
    }
    vector<int>result=dynamicArray(n,querie);
    for(size_t i=0;i<result.size();i++){
        cout<<result[i];
    }
}
```